# Loop through json using jq to get multiple value

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

Here is volumes.json :

```
{
"Volumes": [
    {
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "vol-rescue-system",
                "Key": "Name"
            }
        ],
        "VolumeId": "vol-00112233",
    },
    {
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "vol-rescue-swap",
                "Key": "Name"
            }
        ],
        "VolumeId": "vol-00112234",
    },
    {
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "vol-rescue-storage",
                "Key": "Name"
            }
        ],
        "VolumeId": "vol-00112235",
    }
]
}
```

I need to get both the value of `VolumeId` and `Tags.Value` to be used as the input to invoke another command. It is easy to get a single value from the json array, but I am not able to extract **multiple value** from it and pass it to another bash command.

I can get a single value using this:

```
cat volumes.json |jq -r '.Volumes[].VolumeId' |while read v; do another_bash_command $v; done
```

but I am not able to get multiple value cause this is wrong:

```
 cat volumes.json |jq -r '.Volumes[].VolumeId, .Volumes[].Tags[].Value' |while read v w; do another_bash_command $v $w; done
```

as it will then loop 6 times of the outcome instead of 3.

**And**, how do I pass those multiple json value in the loop to a bash array so I can use the value in a better way ? Like `VolumeId-> $arr[0][0]`, `Tags.Value-> $arr[0][1]`, `AvailabilityZone-> $arr[0][2]`...etc.  I have searched through SO and the jq docs, and tried `readarray`, but still not able to find out the solution :( Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems to me that you want to output the two values (`VolumeId` and `Tags[].Value`) on the same line?

If that's the case, then a simple string concatenation should be enough:

```
$ jq -r '.Volumes[] | .VolumeId + " " + .Tags[].Value' volumes.json
vol-00112233 vol-rescue-system
vol-00112234 vol-rescue-swap
vol-00112235 vol-rescue-storage
```

The above can then be used in a pipeline with `while-read`:

```
jq -r '.Volumes[] | .VolumeId + " " + .Tags[].Value' volumes.json \
| while read -r volumeId tagValue; do
  other_command "$volumeId" "$tagValue"
done
```

You should note that if there is more than one element in `Tags` the result will reflect that. This can however be avoided by referring the first element in `Tags`: `.Tags[0].Value`

Comment: The `IFS=` part seems wrong. You should either remove that or use `IFS=" "` to explicitly set IFS to the space character `" "`. If you keep that then `volumeId` would contain also the tagValue while `tagValue` would be empty.

Comment: @lanoxx yes I think that you are correct.

Answer (score 9):

As @andlrc observed, you may need to decide what you really want in the event that any Tags array has more or less than one element.  Assuming you want `Tags[0]` in all cases, I would recommend considering the use of @tsv as follows:

```
jq -r '.Volumes[] | [.VolumeId, .Tags[0].Value] | @tsv' volumes.json
```

This would be especially appropriate if any of the `.VolumeId` or `.Tags[0].Value` values contained spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.  The point is that @tsv will handle these in a standard way, so that handling the pair of values can be done in a standard way as well.  E.g. using awk, you could read in the pair with `awk -F\\t`; using bash, `IFS=$'\t'`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is about how to get the information using `jq` but its also possible to directly get the expected parameter directly from aws cli using the `--query` flag.

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --query "Volumes[].[VolumeId, Tags[].Value]" --output text
```

Comment: jamespath (used by --query) is awsome for that, pitty there are things you can't do with it that you can do with jq (see eg https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16400320, comment by justin_oaks on Feb 17, 2018).